# Simultaneous equations with instrumental variables

Tags: time-series, stata, instrumental-variables

I am trying to estimate the simultaneous equations model with instruments in STATA.

I have two equations such as:

```
inflation = expected_inflation + output_gap + oil_price + gas_price
output_gap = expected_gap + exchange_rate + interest_rate + oil_price + gas_price
```

I assume that oil and gas prices are exogenous and want to instrument them by its lags.

I guess I should use code like this:

```
reg3 (inf exp_inf gap oil gas) (gap exp_gap real_i reer oil gas), inst(oil gas)
```

However it gives me an error:

```
Equation is not identified -- does not meet order conditions
```

Do you have any ideas what should I do?

Comment: "I assume that oil and gas prices are exogenous and want to instrument them by its lags." Perhaps you meant "endogenous" and "their lags"?

Comment: I hope my answer makes sense as well, doesn't it?

Comment: Exactly. It was too few instruments, that is why it did not work. However, finally I run it in Eviews, not in Stata. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work with Stata, but I tried reading the [manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rreg3.pdf) for the function `reg3` and here is what I think.

Based on the manual, it seems that you should list all the exogenous regressors within `inst( )`; however, you list only two. Stata will interpret this as if all the other variables are endogenous. Then there are too many endogenous variables and too few instruments for the system to be estimated by three stage least squares (3SLS), hence the error message.

Also, I am not sure whether specifying `inst(oil gas)` makes Stata use *lags* of `oil` and `gas` as instruments.

[Here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2002-07/msg00558.html) is a related thread in Stata forum, it arrives to a similar conclusion.